# How do I get the value of a specified field in a specified portal row in filemaker 12?

Tags: portal, filemaker

I have a portal that is auto-sorted so that a specific row of interest comes out on top. I'd like to get the value of a specific field in that row and display it in another field via some calculation.
However I can't figure out how to refer to the values in a specific row.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!
Use the GetRepetition function and specify field and row.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the GetNthRecord function to do this without needing a portal.